# In rust, How to correctly handle references and lifetimes in structure

Tags: rust, reference, lifetime

I have roughly following code structure:

```rust
struct RootStructure<'a> {
    data: Tree,
    import_data: HashMap<String, Tree>
    databases: HashMap<String, Database<'a>>
}

struct Tree {
    ...
}


impl Tree {
    fn get_database(&self) -> Database {
        ...
    }
}

Database <'a> {
    id_refs : HashMap<&str, IdOwner<'a>> 
}

impl<'a> Database<'a> {
    fn get_id(&self, id: &str) -> Option<&IdOwner> {
        ...
    }
}

enum IdOwner <'a> {
    Owner1(&'a Owner1),
    Owner2(&'a Owner2),
}
```

where Tree is big three structure created of bunch of other structs. Some structs have field `id` and I need to be able to search the Tree and find corresponding structure to that Id. Whole Tree is read only.
Enum IdOwner contains all possible reference to the Id having structures in Tree.
I can call get_database() on Tree, which will recursively search the structure for any struct that has ID and adds it to the Database - then returns Database.
Up to this point the code is working.

However problem starts when i have the RootStructure, that has own data and also references to other data. And I am not able to code function that would allow me to insert new Import data and also create database for it and cache it in databases, so I dont have to create database every time I want to search the Tree.

Currently the problem I have is that when I want to add something I do the following

```rust
impl <'a> RootStructure <'a> {
    fn add_import_data (&'a mut self, link: String) {
        ... 
        // Loading Tree node from file
        let tree = Tree.from_file()
        self.import_data.insert("key", tree);
        self.databases.insert("key", self.import_data.get("key").unwrap.get_database())
    }
}
```

Which compiles fine, but after borrowing self mutably for 'a I am unable to interact with the structure in any way. And when I omit the 'a from &mut self, compiler complains that self needs to live as long as the get_databases().

I Hope that by abbreviating the code I did not do some simplification that wont capture the problem.

I am pretty much beginner at Rust, so any recommendations on coding or notes on better architecture  than mine are more than welcome.

Comment: If you are a beginner and you feel that working with deeply nested lifetimes stops you, maybe just use _owning_ references (for example `Rc` or `Arc`). Sure, what you showed _can_ be done, but it usually requires very deep understanding of the whole architecture. And while using references will _technically_ be faster in reality you probably won't even notice it. Lifetimes at their core are a _leaky abstraction_ (which doesn't mean they are not good, or very useful). But tracking a single lifetime throughout full library can be challenging.

Comment: I considered using Rc, but unfortunately the Tree structure does not allow it. It is giant deserialized xml file via quick-xml::de, which I use for the deserialization and does not always work correctly with Structures being encapsulated with Rc<> so that is why I use raw references.

Comment: what do you mean by "not always work correctly with Structures being encapsulated with Rc"? Can you show example of what you tried to do, and what those problems were?

Comment: Well at the time of writting the deserialization (circa two months ago) I had some problem and scratched it. Now I tried it, and can't reproduce the error on simple examples, so maybe I will try using Rc and report If I find any limitations. Thanks for the tip!
Still I would be interested if the question I asked has some answer.